# The message is obvious, no need to decrypt it

Tags: cipher

Today, I saw this strange message on my facebook's wall.
I can't read what she wrote.
but, I know she is struggling with her feeling.

When I asked her, she said the message is obvious, no need to decrypt it.

What does the message say?

```
   1 \/\/1$!-! 1 /\/3\/312 11137 yo!_! $o 1 \/\/o!_!|_!>/\/'7 !-!4\/3 
   f4|_|_3/\/ fo12 yo!_! 4/\/!> 1 \/\/o!_!|_!>/\/'7 !-!4\/3 7o $712!_!gg!_3 
   \/\/17!-! 111y f33|_1/\/g c4!_!$3 1 !</\/o\/\/ 17$ 1111po$$113|_3. 
   P|_34$3 73|_|_ 1113 \/\/!-!47 7o !>o, $!-!o!_!|_!> 1 j!_!$7 
   !<33p !>1$74/\/c3 4/\/!> 712y 7o fo12g37 yo!_!?
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The message is simply:

> `I WISH I NEVER MET YOU SO I WOULDN'T HAVE
>
>  FALLEN FOR YOU AND I WOULDN'T HAVE TO STRUGGLE
>
>  WITH MY FEELING CAUSE I KNOW ITS IMPOSSIBLE.
>
>  PLEASE TELL ME WHAT TO DO, SHOULD I JUST
>
>  KEEP DISTANCE AND TRY TO FORGET YOU?`

The "encoding" is

> a form of [leetspeak](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leet), replacing letters with punctuation and numbers that look similar. For instance, `U` is replaced with `!_!` and `N` with `/\/`.